# How can I get custom HTTP error messages?

Tags: javascript, api, http, request

Here im making a request to from the frontend to backend:

```js
await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/signin", data) // <- sending wrong data
        .then()
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));  // <-- here the response is 404
```

Here i make the request to the mongodb:

```js
const signin = async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!existingUser) return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found." });
};

router.route("/signin").post(signin)
```

Bacically i want when the user sends wrong data i want the `err.message` i get to be `"User not found."`  but it is `Request failed with status code 404`.
Why?

Comment: Does your `router` variable handle request to `/users` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `err.message` is not where the JSON data is stored; Instead use `err.response.data` (`err.response` is the actual response from the web server, `err` is what is raised by the `axios.post()` failing)